# Change password for a user in secured.mdw file

Tags: ms-access-2016, mdw

I'm supporting a lot of old Access Reports and one of the reports authenticates its users against a Microsoft Access Workgroup Information file (`Secured.mdw` file).

Now, one of the users forgot his password and I need to reset it for him.
I'm not the creator of that `Secured.mdw` file but I can open it and view the users.

This is what I've tried so far:

**Step 1:**
Opened the database by double clicking the `Secured.mdw` file

[image]

**Step 2:**
Viewed the Users. (For eg: I want to change password for user: *bandaj1*)

[image]

**Step 3:**
File -> Users and Permissions -> User and Group Accounts

[image]

**Step 4:**
I can't locate *bandaj1* user. In fact, I can't locate any user other than *admin* user. 
[image]

Am I even heading in the right direction?

Please suggest on how to go about changing password for users in Access Workgroup Information file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The part that I was missing was that I had to specify which database to open with this `.mdw` file

### Step 1:

Open the `MyApp.mdb` database *using* the `.mdw` file using this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.mdb" /WRKGRP "C:\Program Files\MyApp\Secured.mdw"
```

### Step 2:

Log in using Admin credentials:

[image]

### Step 3:

*File --> Users and Permissions --> User and Group Accounts*
[image]

### Step 4:

Find the user whose password you want to reset. For eg: I'm going with *bandaj1* here.
[image]

Now hit *Clear Password* button.
Click *Ok* and close the file.

### Step 5:

Tell *bandaj1* user to login without a password and tell them to set their own password.

### Step 6:

*bandaj1* user logs in successfully without a password now:
[image]

### Step 7:

*bandaj1* user goes to *File --> Users and Permissions --> User and Group Accounts* to setup a new password.

### Step 8:

*bandaj1* user selects *Change Logon Password* tab. And sets a new password:
[image]

*bandaj1* user hits *Apply* and *Ok* to close the widow.

### Step 9:

*bandaj1* user's password is successfully reset, and he'll use the password he set in Step 8 to log in next time.